# How to get the password from Kerberos principal

Tags: kerberos, livy

For all the auto-generated Kerberos principals, for example HDFS, Hadoop, Livy, how can I get their passwords so that I can try `kinit` with it?

I created a Kerberized cluster in AWS EMR and by default it auto-generated all these principals, and now I want to actually be able to authenticate Kerberos with them, but I don't know their passwords.

How can I get their passwords, and since I have their keytabs can I get their passwords from the keytabs?

Comment: Recommended reading: the `man` page of `kinit`. Especially options `-k` and `-t`.

Comment: Note that you are talking about **service** principals. Stuff used by machines. Unless you are a cyborg, you should probably create a **user** principal and use it, well, to authenticate _against_ the services...

Comment: ...especially since some of the service principals are black-listed for some operations (a kind of fool-proof measure).